# Why does double x = 0,1; not compile?

Tags: c++, syntax, comma-operator

```
double x = 0,1;
```

doesn't compile (tries on on MSVC9.0). The error is

```
C2059 syntax error : 'constant'
```

I *do* realize that there's a comma there instead of a point, but shouldn't the line above be interpreted as the following?

```
double x = (0,1); //which is double x = 1;
```

Incidentally, the initialization compiles successfully with the parentheses.

I was thinking along the lines that `operator ,` has a lower precedence than `operator =`, but in this case `=` is no operator, so this shouldn't be an issue. What syntactic rules determine that

```
 double x = 0,1;
```

should be illegal?

Comment: Isn't this just because normally you have `double x = 0, y;`?

Comment: Interesting question, initially I thought it should compile too. :)

Comment: note that if you write `double(x)(1), y;` that is a valid declaration but can also be parsed as an expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

During declarations, the comma in the absence of parenthesis is treated as a separator between declarations.  For example:

```
double x = 0, y = 1;
```

or

```
double x = 0, y;
```

What you typed is the equivalent of

```
double x = 0;
double 1;
```

Which is obviously not correct.

Answer (score 11):

Well, it's treated as

```
double x = 0; double 1;
```

that's why. Just like you'd write

```
double x = 0, y;
```

It's the syntax for a declaration, you're just attempting to declare `1` as a variable (which is wrong). Don't think there's much more to it...